# How can I write to a form textbox from another object without having to return

Tags: windows, winforms

I am working on a Windows Application form and I have a multi-line textbox that I would like to write output from another object.  I saw there was a similar posting about getting text from one textbox to another form's textbox.  However, I am working with the mainform and can't new up another one.

So how can I assign values to the mainform's .Text from another class?

Comment: What do you mean "from another object"?  What and where is that other class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create public properties on the form that get or set control properties e.g.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        

    ...

    public string OperatorId 
    { 
        get { return OperatorIdField.Text.Trim().ToLower(); }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return PasswordField.Text.Trim().ToLower(); }
    }

    ...

}
```

(OperatorIdField and PasswordField are textboxes. In my example, the properties are read only i.e. they only have "get" methods. In your case you'd have to add "set" methods as well).

To expose the main form to other objects, you can create a static member that exposes the main form e.g.

```
static class Program
{
    public static Form MainForm;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        MainForm = new Form1();

        Application.Run(MainForm);
    }
}
```

When another object needs to get the password, the code would be something like:

```
string password = Program.MainForm.Password;
```

Answer (score 1):

Second form should have some event, that you call once you need change text box value in main form. And main form should be subscribed to this event and change text in at some eventHandler.